# Function: is this binary search tree "odd balanced"?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

If the number of odd descendents on the left == number of odd descendents on the right, the tree is "odd balanced".

```
public boolean isOddBalanced() {   
    return (isOddBalanced (root) >= 0);
}
private int isOddBalanced (Node x) {
    if (x == null) return 0;
    int ls = isOddBalanced (x.left);
    int rs = isOddBalanced (x.right);
    if (Math.abs (ls - rs) > 0) return -1;
    else return 0;
}
```

I'm stuck on how to count & compare the number of odd keys on each side. Any insight would be appreciated.

Trying to implement ideas from @nem:

```
public boolean isOddBalanced() {   
    return (isOddBalanced (root, '0') >= 0);
}
private int isOddBalanced (Node x, char side) {
    int count = 0;
    if (x == null) return 0;
    count = isOddBalanced (x.left, 'l');
    count = isOddBalanced (x.right, 'r');
    if (x.key % 2 != 0 && side == 'l') count += 1;
    if (x.key % 2 != 0 && side == 'r') count -= 1;
    if (count != 0) return -1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: By number of  **odd descendents**, you mean the number of child nodes that hold an odd value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is a way of counting odd-value nodes through the recursion.

You can achieve this using a wrapper class (since Java is [pass-by-value](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)):

```
class OddCounter {
    int count = 0;
}
```

Now what you can do, instead of counting the left or right odd-value nodes separately, you can just add 1 to the `count` each time a left odd-value node is found and deduct 1 from the `count` each time a right odd-value node is found.
This means that, if the tree is odd-balanced, the `count` variable will be 0.

Your code would look something like this:

```
public boolean isOddBalanced() { 
    OddCounter c = new OddCounter();  
    isOddBalancedHelper(root, c, '0');
    return (c.count == 0);
}

private void isOddBalancedHelper (Node x, OddCounter c, char comingFrom) {
    if (x == null) return;
    isOddBalancedHelper(x.left, c, 'l');  
    isOddBalancedHelper(x.right, c, 'r'); 
    if(x.value % 2 != 0 && comingFrom == 'l') {        // if current node is odd and a left child
        c.count++;
    } else if(x.value % 2 != 0 && comingFrom == 'r') { // if current node is odd and a right child
        c.count--;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** based on your comment (without using any extra classes or functions)

What you can do is use an instance variable instead of a counter class:

```
int oddCount;                       // use an instance variable to count the difference between the amount of left odd-nodes and right odd-nodes

public boolean isOddBalanced() { 
    this.oddCount = 0;              // reset count each time balance is calculated to ensure answer is correct each time (and not just on the first call)
    isOddBalancedHelper(root, '0');
    return (this.oddCount == 0);
}

private void isOddBalancedHelper (Node x, char comingFrom) {
    if (x == null) return;
    isOddBalancedHelper(x.left, 'l');  
    isOddBalancedHelper(x.right, 'r'); 
    if(x.value % 2 != 0 && comingFrom == 'l') {        // if current node is odd and a left child
        this.oddCount++;
    } else if(x.value % 2 != 0 && comingFrom == 'r') { // if current node is odd and a right child
        this.oddCount--;
    }
}
```

Another improvement you could make is to cash the value of `oddCount` and only update it if the tree content is altered in any way (nodes are added/removed, node values are changed).

This would allow you to calculate the value of `isOddBalanced()` only once per tree structure.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use any other functions / classes.

Comment: Look at my edit for a possible solution then. Also, when you say `the number of odd descendents on the left == number of odd descendents on the right`, does this apply to **every** node in the tree? That is, does **each sub-tree** have to be odd-balanced for the whole tree to be odd-balanced? This is what my answer shows you how to do. Or does it simply mean that the amount of nodes left of root that have an odd value must equal to the amount of nodes right of root that have an odd value?

Comment: Suppose you have a perfect binary tree with 7 nodes, 'A' through 'G' in in-order. Assume also nodes `A`, `B`, `E` and `G` are odd (that is, two odd nodes on each side of the root node `D`). As far as I could trace your code it will answer the tree rooted at node `D` is **not** odd-balanced — nodes `A`, `B` and `E` are left children of their respective parents (`comingFrom == 'l'`), so they cause incrementing the counter, and node `G` is a right-child  (`comingFrom == 'r'`), so it decrements the counter, thus the final result of  `oddCount == 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Give a look at this.

```
private int countNode(Node x){
    if(x == null) return 0;
    else return countNode(x.left) + countNode(x.right) + 1;
}

private bool isOddBalanced(Node x){
    int ls = countNode(x.left);
    int rs = countNode(x.right);
    return (ls == rs);
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP needs to check if the number of nodes on each side that **contain odd values** is equal, not if the number of nodes on each side is equal

Comment: This is pretty odd for me, i didnt undestand then :/!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to know if the number of odd descendents on the left == number of odd descendants on the right, you only need the diference between left and right childs.

```
public boolean isOddBalanced() {   
    return (CountChilds(root.left) == CountChilds(root.right));
}
private int CountChilds(Node x) {
    if (x == null) return 0;
    // left childs + right childs + me
    else return CountChilds(x.left) + CountChilds(x.right) + 1; 
}
```

Comment: Is basically the same i did... and is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems ill–formed.

> If the number of odd descendents on the left == number of odd descendents on the right, the tree is "odd balanced".

That means you need to compare the number of the root node's left odd descendants to the number of the root node's right odd descendants. However that is *not* the usual way to define properies for trees — such properties are usually defined for *each node* in a tree. That means you would need to check the odd–balance in every node of the tree.

You can do that in a single recursive pass traversing the whole tree, just like @nem said. However you can improve the solution a bit.

Note that once we defined the odd–balance as a recursive property, then the tree will not be odd–balanced if any its sub–tree is unbalanced. So while recurring, we can retrieve the information both on the number of odd nodes *and* on the balance. How can we do that without a composite container for two results? Well, if a subtree is unbalanced, the whole tree is unbalanced, right? So we already know the whole tree is unbalanced, hence do not need information about number of nodes. Thus we can return these mutualy exclusive pieces of information as a single `int` value: zero or positive for number of odd nodes in an *odd–balanced* subtree, or negative for unbalanced subtree.

```
private int isOddBalanced (Node x) {
    // empty tree is balanced and it contains no odd nodes
    if (x == null) return 0;

    // check subtrees; if any is unbalanced, return the status up the tree
    int ls = isOddBalanced (x.left);
    // don't test the right subtree if the left one is unbalanced
    if (ls < 0) return -1;

    int rs = isOddBalanced (x.right);
    if (rs < 0) return -1;

    // when both are balanced test for odd-nodes numbers equality
    if (ls != rs) return -1;

    // return the current sub-total
    return ls + rs + ((x.key % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1);
}
```